# To generate a subset of size n one by one to reduce the complexity?

Tags: c++, subset

```
void AlgoMMPCbar::subs(const std::vector<unsigned int>& org, const std::vector<unsigned int>& pre, size_t k, size_t n, SubSets& c){
   if (n <= 1) {
    for(size_t i = k; i < org.size(); i++){
        std::vector<unsigned int> v(pre);// instead of printing...
        v.push_back(org.at(i));
        c.push_back(v);
    }
} else {
    size_t n1 = n - 1;
    for(size_t i = k; i != org.size() - n1; i++){   // 
        std::vector<unsigned int> s(pre);
        s.push_back(org.at(i));
        subs(org,s,i+1,n1,c);
    }
}
}
void AlgoMMPCbar::computeSubSets(const std::vector<unsigned int>& org, size_t& n, SubSets& c){
 c.clear(); // clear previous data

std::vector<unsigned int> pre;
pre.reserve(n+1); // for performance
    if (n==0)
      c.push_back(pre);
else
        subs(org,pre,0, n, c); 
}
```

The above code used to generate subsets of size n for further test/processing. But i never need to test all these generated subsets (in worst case it will check them all). The main time consuming part of the program is the subset generation. Now i want to transform the above functionality to generate subsets one by one (not all at once, so, i can stop further subset generation any time).

Please share your expertise to transform the above functionality in a function like subset.next(), to save computational time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say `ind` maintains the indexes for elements in the subset in an increasing order, i.e.

```
ind[0] < ind[1] < ... < ind[n-1]
```

find the smallest `j` such that

```
j == n-1 || ind[j] + 1 < ind[j+1]
```

you may go to the next subset by

```
ind[j]++
ind[0] = 0; ind[1] = 1; ... ind[j-1] = j-1
```

note that the new `ind` array is still sorted. You may easily show that starting with

```
ind[] = [0, 1, ..., n-1]
```

you will generate all the subsets iterating through above procedure. you can have a fast code if you use some tricks for 'maintaining' the value of `j` in above rather than doing a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your `subs` function return a `bool`. In the `n<=1` branch of your `if`, you can run the respective checks, and if the current subset matches, you save it and you return `true`. In the other branch you replace the `subs` call by something like `if (subs(..)) return true;`. And you add a `return false` at the end.
I have no idea what you should do if you potentially need more than one subset, and you don't know exactly how many suitable ones there are.

Comment: The generated subsets will be used for independence test, if independence found for subset(i), then no need to check for further subsets. If i first generate all subsets then start testing, it takes lot of time. So, i would like to generate subsets one by one to save time.

Answer (score 0):

I would create some sort state vector and step through it lexicographically. So if you have a set of `M` elements and you want subsets of size `n`, you'd have a vector `n` integers corresponding to the selected indices. Then you make an algorithm `next_subset(std::vector<bool> &)` which gets the next subset. E.g for size-3 subsets of 5:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
```

I'm sure you can spot the pattern (increment the last place; if it's at the end, move it back and increment the two last places up, etc etc).

If you want to be a bit more efficient, you can store iterators to your original container, or pairs of integers and iterators if the container isn't random-access.

Comment: Yes, i am already generating subsets step by step e.g. for n=1, n=2 ...  Now, i want to generate each element one by one. "if you want to be a bit more efficient, you can store iterators to your original container, or pairs of integers and iterators if the container isn't random-access." can you give me an example of code please? thanks

Comment: Well, suppose you have a `std::vector<T> TheSet;`. Then you can make a `std::vector<std::vector<T>::const_iterator>` of `n` iterators and use the distance from `TheSet.begin()` to each iterator as the index... if you don't have a vector, you can make a vector of, say, `std::pair<size_t, std::list<T>::const_iterator>` for the indexing.